# how to write a rewriteCond in .htaccess to exclude a subdir and its subdirs

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have the following problem. I have a website and a blog in a subdirectory. Both of them are php. I have a .htaccess file in the root folder and another one in the blog folder. I dont' think is relevant, but the blog script is wordpress.

I added a condition in the root .htaccess to skip the requests made for the blog,

```
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog.*
```

Here it is how it looks. I removed the rest of the file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase / RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/

// my added line RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog.*


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. RewriteRule .* http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(all)/([^/]+)/?$ story.php?title=$2 [L] RewriteRule ^(all)/?$ ?category=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php [L] RewriteRule ^advanced-search/?$ advancedsearch.php [L] ...
```

The problem I have is related to the blog requests. For example sometimes if I try to open an url it works fine, sometimes the home (root page not the blog) is opened. It seems very strange. I think it is related to the host. When the host is to busy the blog page I request is not found so the request is going to the root .htaccess.

I have 2 questions:

- how to write a rule and where to
  place it to exclude all the requests
  for /blog to be rewritten by the root
  .htaccess? the blog requests might
  look like http: //test.com/blog,
  http: //test.com/blog/,
  http: //test.com/blog/title,
  http: //test.com/blog/title/,
  http: //test.com/blog/category/title
- does anyone has any idea what happens? Why when I open a blog page it opens the home root page, and if I refresh the page it goes to the blog post page?

Comment: Could you please format the code so that it is more "readable" (= newlines at the right places)? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look into the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), specifically the -d flag in RewriteCond.

It should be something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule HERE
```